# Generalise rendering of a tree of unknown nodes

Tags: java

What I am trying to do isn't easy; I do realize that. But I would think there is some better way that what I cooked up. Here's the Problem: I am trying to write a generic class to render a Tree that stores Nodes which are evaluable - for example, a Node could be storing a value and just evaluating to that value, or it could be generating a random value, or be an operation on a number of other Nodes - hence I say tree, but the truth is that the internal state of the Node is unknown (for example, a Node may have 0,1,2 or more Node fields for the Children, or an ArrayList of children etc). Of course this wouldn't be an issue if each Node knew how to render itself, but I am trying to avoid this. (Ideally, I would like to be able to render the Tree to a String or as an OpenGL graphic or whatever just by changing the Renderer). Oh and please don't ask questions like "What good would that be?" because I'm just doing this because it seemed interesting.

(By now I figured that I could at least give Nodes the knowledge that they CAN be rendered, and the ability to decide the logical structure of the rendering, but this probably wouldn't improve this too much)

This is what I have so far:
An interface for the Nodes

```
public interface Node<T> {
    T evaluate();
}
```

A class for value nodes:

```
public class ValueNode<T> implements Node<T> {
    private T value;
    @Override
    public T evaluate() {
        return value;
    }

    public ValueNode(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

A general class for binary operators:

```
public abstract class BinaryOperator<A, B, T> implements Node<T> {
    private Node<A> left;
    private Node<B> right;

    public BinaryOperator(Node<A> left, Node<B> right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Node<A> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Node<B> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

}
```

A class for Integer addition:

```
/**
 * I couldn't figure out a generic way to add 2 numbers,
 * so I'm going with just Integer for now.
 *
 */
public class IntegerAdditionNode extends BinaryOperator<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    public IntegerAdditionNode (Node<Integer> left, Node<Integer> right) {
        super(left,right);
    }

    public Integer evaluate() {
        return getLeft().evaluate() + getRight().evaluate();
    }
}
```

And finally, an example string renderer class that allows for new rendering options to be added dynamically. It's extremely ugly though, and I would really appreciate ideas or just a light push in the right direction how I could do this one better:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NodeToString {
    public interface RenderMethod {
        public <T extends Node<?>> String renderNode(T node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test
        NodeToString renderer = new NodeToString();
        RenderMethod addRender = new RenderMethod() {
            private NodeToString render;

            public RenderMethod addNodeToString(NodeToString render) {
                this.render = render;
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public <T extends Node<?>> String renderNode(T node) {
                IntegerAdditionNode addNode = (IntegerAdditionNode) node;
                return render.render(addNode.getLeft()) +"+"+render.render(addNode.getRight());
            }
        }.addNodeToString(renderer);

        renderer.addRenderMethod(IntegerAdditionNode.class, addRender);

        RenderMethod valueRender = new RenderMethod () {

            @Override
            public <T extends Node<?>> String renderNode(T node) {
                return ((ValueNode<?>)node).evaluate().toString();
            }

        };

        //I don't know why I have to cast here. But it doesn't compile
        //if I don't.
        renderer.addRenderMethod((Class<? extends Node<?>>) ValueNode.class,
                                 valueRender);

        Node<Integer> node = new IntegerAdditionNode(new ValueNode<Integer>(2),
                                                    new ValueNode<Integer>(3));
        System.out.println(renderer.render(node));

    }

    private HashMap<Class<? extends Node<?>>, RenderMethod> renderMethods = new
            HashMap<Class<? extends Node<?>>, NodeToString.RenderMethod>();

    /**
     * Renders a Node
     * @param node
     * @return
     */
    public <T extends Node<?>> String render(T node) {
        Class nodeType = node.getClass();
        if(renderMethods.containsKey(nodeType)) {
            return renderMethods.get(nodeType).renderNode(node);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Node Type");
        }

    }

    /**
     * This adds a rendering Method for a specific Node type to the Renderer
     * @param nodeType
     * @param method
     */
    public void addRenderMethod(Class<? extends Node<?>> nodeType, RenderMethod method) {
        renderMethods.put(nodeType, method);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not try a visitor pattern?

Comment: That won't work - every time I'd add a new Node type I'd have to change the visitor interface. Visitor is great if you want to add operations without changing the data structure, but in my case I'd want to be able to add new kinds of data (new nodes in this case) AND add new operations (additional rendering methods). Honestly, I'm not so sure if there even is a good way to do this.

Comment: You need to add the renderer somewhere no matter what.

Comment: No the thing with visitor is, that I'd need each operation to implement the visitor pattern. Which in turn means, that every time I add a new kind of Node I'd have to break the visitor interface open, add a new visit method for that node type, and then implement that visit method in every single class that implements the interface. In other words, adding new Node types will force me to change every single renderer - of course in some sense this is a sensible solution, because it would get rid of undefined cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know you say that you are "trying to avoid this" but I really think the `Node` should have a `render()` method on it.  If you don't want the render code to be in each node type then you could do something like:

```
public class ValueNode<T> implements Node<T> {
    private static RenderMethod rendorMethod;
    public static void setRendorMethod(RenderMethod rendorMethod) {
        ValueNode.rendorMethod = rendorMethod;
    }
    ...
    public String render() {
        rendorMethod(this);
    }
```

The way you are doing it will work although I found it unnecessarily complicated.  Some comments:

1. `renderer.addRenderMethod(IntegerAdditionNode.class, addRender)`

   Calling `addRenderMethod` with a value of `addRender` took me a while to understand for obvious reasons since `add` has multiple meanings here.  Maybe using the verb put which matched the `Map` is better.
2. Calling `NodeToString.render()` from within your `addRender()` was confusing although I understand the need.
3. Method is an overloaded term in Java which makes `RenderMethod` seem like a Java method not a way of rendering.  How about `NodeRenderer` or just `Renderer`?
4. Assigning `NodeString` to the variable `renderer` just is strange.  It is very different from an `addRender` or `valueRender` since it is not a `RenderMethod`.  Maybe it should be?
5. In all `main` classes, the first thing I do in the `main` method is to do something like the following.  This makes it less complicated for me at least:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new NodeString().doMain(args);
   }
   private void doMain(String[] args) {
       ...
   ```